# ¿Cómo me conecto a esta ip con puerto de una base de datos?

Tags: mysql, server

*Antes que nada no se si este bien formulada la pregunta, no tengo claro como preguntarlo.*

**Problema:**

Tengo un servidor con una `ip` esta tiene un puerto para pocer acceder a este.

Ejemplo: **`190.212.120.100:5000`**

Cuando entro al navegador ingreso la url y agrego **`/phpmyadmin`**   Completo: **`190.212.120.100:5000/phpmyadmin`**

Ingresa bien, pero me gustaria poder usarlo por ejemplo en **Navicat** (administrador gráfico de base de datos).

Quiero saber si es algo del servidor que debo configurar por que ya tengo los usuarios "remotos" y de hecho con esos son los que conecto cuando entro a esa ip.

Comment: esa.. no es la ip de la base de datos.. esa ip es de phpmyadmin... Ni idea cual seria la ip de tu base de datos, pero a esa deberias conectarte desde cualquier otro lado. Igual, no termino de entender tu pregunta....

Comment: Seguramente ese phpmyadmin está configurado para conectarse a un servidor mysql/mariadb que se ejecuta en la misma IP (aunque no tiene porque, pero es lo habitual).  Ten en cuenta que mysql, por defecto, corre en el puerto 3306, y lo que tu ves en el puerto 5000 es un servidor http desde donde se ejecuta el phpmyadmin.  Por lo tanto seguramente en Navicat debes poner la IP y el puerto 3306, o sea, 190.212.120.100:3306.  Si no te funciona debes preguntar al admin del servidor en que puerto corre el mysql, pero el 5000 no será seguro, o bien que te de acceso a ese puerto desde tu IP (firewall).

Comment: Puedes comprobar si ese servidor tiene abierto el puerto 3306 mediante herramientas como nmap o Zenmap, saludos.

Comment: Comprueba donde se está conectando ese phpmyadmin, y así sabras de forma certera que parametro usar para el host de navicat.  Para ello mirate esta imagen: https://i.stack.imgur.com/No2Iw.png  y haz click en (1) y comprueba que sale en (2), y ese es el dato que debes usar (a menos que te salga un localhost, pero entonces mira solo el puerto y usa la IP publica más ese puerto para acceder)

Comment: @masterguru, [imagen](https://prnt.sc/26gdkb8) solo me aparece localhost ese es el phpmyadmin con la ip publica y el puerto que me proporcionaron.
[https://prnt.sc/26gdoqe](https://prnt.sc/26gdoqe) aqui hago lo siguiente. **1.** ingreso ip, **2**el puerto ese no se si dejarlo con el 3306 o el que me proporcionan igual da ese error con cualquiera de los dos puertos.

Comment: el tipo de conexión en el navicat igual probe con mysql y mariadb el resultado es el mismo.

Comment: En esa conexión veo que lo intentas con el usuario root... ¿tienes ese usuario en ese servidor?

Comment: si con ese ingreso desde el navegador.

Comment: O sea, que es un servidor dedicado, ¿no?  ¿Y no tienes acceso a su SSH?  Desde alli puedes ver en que puerto corre facilmente, solo para asegurarte de cual es.

Comment: voy a revisar, gracias

Comment: Solo para descartar otros problemas, ¿porque no pruebas si te funciona la conexion a los servidores de pruebas de navicat?  En esta página hay uno para mysql: http://navicat.com/manual/online_manual/en/navicat_16/linux_manual/#/connection_0... a ver si te conectas al menos a ese

Comment: El problema no es navicat, ya tengo algunas conexiones realizadas [https://prnt.sc/26ge03q](https://prnt.sc/26ge03q), igual adjunto prueba del ejemplo.

Comment: Vale, era para ir descartando cosas :-)

Comment: Asi pues, si eso es un servidor dedicado, debes poder administrarlo y quizas tiene un firewall que esta bloqueando el puerto del mysql que dices que te han dado, por lo tanto tocaria abrirlo totalmente o solo para tu IP.  Mira que tipo de acceso tienes a el

Comment: @masterguru, ya solucione el problema, el error fue que cuando redirecciono en el firewall apunto al puerto 80 y no al puerto 3306 y modifique eso y listo puedo usar el puerto `XXXX` que agregue para acceder y funciona.
Muchas gracias.

Comment: Por fin!  Estos problemas "fantasma" acaban siendo un poco agónicos porque no tienen mucho sentido hasta que se encuentra algo que nada tiene que ver con lo preguntado :-) Me alegro por ti y gracias por avisar.

Comment: @masterguru, asi es, mil gracias y disculpas por que si el problema no tiene nada que ver con lo que pregunte. no se si deba borrarl la pregunta o que hacer.

Comment: si gustas pon tu sugerencia para marcarla como la que me ayudo por que en realiadad por tu comentario de puede que el firewall este bloqueando un puerto, me fui para esa area y pude darme cuenta del "error".

Comment: No te preocupes, borra la pregunta directamente, nos hemos pasado tres pueblos con tantos comentarios, más bien parece un chat :-)  Me alegro que lo consiguieras al fin. Saludos!